# why this Error : A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network [2a00:1450:4008:c01::6c]:25

Tags: c#, sockets, easendmail

I am trying to send email from C# desktop application ,I referred this page for doing this `http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=0` here is my code but it is giving me following exception

`A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network [2a00:1450:4008:c01::6c]:25`

at this line

`oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);`
Where I am going wrong

```
private void sendmail()
        {
            SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
            EASendMail.SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();

            oMail.From = "mo@gmail.com";

            oMail.To = "mo@gmail.com";

            oMail.Subject = "test email from c# project";

            oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project, do not reply";

            // Your SMTP server address
            SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");

            // User and password for ESMTP authentication,            
            oServer.User = "mo@gmail.com";
            oServer.Password = "account password here";   


            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start to send email ...");
                oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);//getting error here
                Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
```

Comment: it seems socket is closed

Comment: `SmtpMail` is deprecated.

Comment: How should I make it working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700115/how-to-send-email-to-gmail-using-smtpclient-in-c

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes Its working Now I referred Link u suggested